# How should I do the graphics for a simple python program?

Tags: python

I'm building a simple python program that will back up data with the options of compressing it or not. It also will have a built in schedule function.

I built this already for a console application, but I want to have a GUI. I found that I could use Tkinter to program the graphics, but is this the best/most efficient way? Is there like a designer IDE I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider the use of [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey). It automatically creates a GUI for you based on the `ArgumentParser` settings. It is really useful to turn simple CLI programs into GUI ones.

[image]

Comment: 1Wow, this seems awesome! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, mark the answer as accepted if your problem is solved.

Comment: Don't worry I will, just have to wait for the timer.